# What brand is my chain?

Tags: chain

[image]

It has '3f-2' stamped on the plates but I can't tell what the brand is. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need to know a chain brand? It looks like a regular cheap chain to me, no cutouts or hollow pins like on more expensive offerings.

Comment: The plate below the thumbnail says TEC (?). What determines the chain is the number of sprockets at the rear and the number of links. Buy an x-speed chain, 'x' being the number of sprockets. Chains are sold in lengths that are greater than needed. So you'll need a chain cutter tool. For easier fitting get a chain with a quick link. There are plenty of videos on the Net to explain the procedure.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't matter. Chains are commodity components made to standard sizes, and the chain you have doesn't seem to be a high-end chain, as it has none of the weight-saving cut-outs that a fancier chain would have.

You need to get a chain that's the same width and has the same number of links. The width is determined by the number of cogs you have on the rear axle (and chains are literally sold as, e.g., a ten-speed chain). You'll need to shorten the new chain to the same length as your current one by breaking links with a chain tool; there are plenty of videos on YouTube that will explain how to do this, or just get your local bike shop to do the work for you.